# How to remove Henna color from acrylic practice hand board?

Tags: color

I had purchased the acrylic hand for practicing henna design. I applied henna in it but the color is not going. Please provide a solution to clear the color from it or else it won't be of any use to me.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hydrogen peroxide can work to remove it, you can also try lemon juice 1:1 with baking Soda after the peroxide.  Strong hydrogen peroxide is likely to be more effective but not too important, it is highly reactive so make sure you clean thoroughly with a cloth before using it.

Depending on the type of plastic you can try strong acetone.  However note that acetone will react with and melt some plastics and it is also highly flammable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cotton round and nail polish remover to remove the stained henna from the acrylic hand.

Comment: That answer has already been given.  Nail polish remover is acetone-based.  As the other answer states, acetone can soften or dissolve some acrylics.